# Importing a SQL Dump File through XAMPP's Command Line

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, command-line

A few days ago, I exported a .SQL dump file with all my databases, which is about 150MB. The thing is I cannot import it through phpMyAdmin since the file is way to big.

I remembered there was BigDump and I tried to use it, since it's ideal for such big imports as mine. The problem is that I need to set a database to import the dump file on, which is something I cannot do, since the dump file contains some databases I dumped, meaning that BigDump needs a database to be configured with so it can import the file.

I've been searching around and found out that one option could be using XAMPP's mysql.exe command line, which I already tried to, but since the import command requires a database to make the import, it makes it impossible.

Do you have any another idea or know how to make an import without the need to provide a database?

Regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the tool and parameters used to create the .sql dump file of multiple databases, the file will normally have

```
CREATE DATABASE DBn...;
```

and

```
USE DBn;
```

statements that will allow your import to proceed without hiccups. For example, both the mysqldump command [mysqldump command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html%20'mysqldump%20command') and phpMyAdmin's Export function for multiple database insert them.

Assuming you have exported with a sensible tool like those above, then you can import the database with a command line like this:

```
mysql -u username -p < dumpfile.sql
```

Your mysql username account needs to have appropriate privileges to, for example, create databases.

You can even run this command in a more familiar way by naming the startingDB database to use before running the commands in `dumpfile.sql`:

```
mysql -u username -p startingDB < dumpfile.sql
```

As the dumpfile will have a `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` before any `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements, everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, mustaccio. I'm just getting my feet wet here, as my rep shows! Cheers.

Comment: I'm having the following error while performing that command: "ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 29: No database selected".

Comment: Open up the sql dumpfile in an editor (I like to use simple low level ones when working with massive files), and check if there are any USE db statements and CREATE DATABASE statements in it. Also, could you share more the tool / command you used to create it?

Comment: I used phpMyAdmin to export all the databases. By the way, what do I have to do when I find 'USE' and 'CREATE DATABASE' statements?

Comment: It's good that those statements arr there - your dump sounds fine.  I would put a USE db; statement before the troublesome line, maybe on line1, for some existing db. Also, could you post a pastebin link to a snippet of the start of the file past line29 to the fist USE db; statement?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

Open XAMPP, click on the "Shell" button on the right.

The shell start with command prompt, now enter:

```
mysql -u root -p <DB_NAME> < <your-file-location
```

Example:

```
mysql -u root -p -v db_dummy < "D:\backups\hugedb.sql"
```

If you are asked for `Password:` just hit enter.

The `-v` will output the entire import processes to your screen. Remove it if you don't need it.